# jQuery Rearrange HTML Inside Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML like this -

```
<div class="outerDiv" id="od_1">
    <label>Div 1</label>
    <div class="innerDiv">Inner Div 1</div>
    <div class="innerDiv">Inner Div 2</div>
    <div class="innerDiv">Inner Div 3</div>
</div>
<div class="outerDiv" id="od_2">
    <label>Div 2</label>
    <div class="innerDiv">Inner Div 1</div>
    <div class="innerDiv">Inner Div 2</div>
    <div class="innerDiv">Inner Div 3</div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve through jQuery is this -

```
<div class="outerDiv" id="od_1">
    <label>Div 1</label>
    <div class="innerDivBox">
        <div class="innerDiv">Inner Div 1</div>
        <div class="innerDiv">Inner Div 2</div>
        <div class="innerDiv">Inner Div 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="outerDiv" id="od_2">
    <label>Div 2</label>
    <div class="innerDivBox">
        <div class="innerDiv">Inner Div 1</div>
        <div class="innerDiv">Inner Div 2</div>
        <div class="innerDiv">Inner Div 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I started with looping through div with class "outerDiv" -

```
$('.outerDiv').each(function(i, obj) {
     var divId = this.id;                    
});
```

But I am not sure how exactly I should proceed from here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `find()` and `wrapAll()` to group the inner divs with a common parent:

```
$('.outerDiv').each(function(i, obj) {
    $(this).find('.innerDiv').wrapAll('<div class="innerDivBox">');
});
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hjgab/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.outerDiv').each(function() {
    $(this).append( $('<div class="innerDivBox"></div>').append( $(this).find('.innerDiv') ) );
});
```